# INSERT stmt in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am new to HQL, 
want to insert data directly into database using INSERT stmt. when using following code:
CompanyMaster is the model name(**CompanyMaster.java**)

```
public void insertCompanyData(CompanyMaster company) {
    logger.info("Entering insertCompanyData");

    Session session = null;
    try{
        session = getSession();
        String hql = "INSERT INTO CompanyMaster (CompName,description,status) SELECT  (company.getCompName(),company.getDescription(),company.getStatus())";
        //String hql = "INSERT INTO CompanyMaster company(CompName,description,status) VALUES (company.getCompName(),company.getDescription(),company.getStatus())";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        //query.setString("groupId", groupId);
        query.executeUpdate();
    } finally{
        releaseSession(session);
    }

    logger.info("Exiting insertCompanyData");
}
```

i am getting error like this

```
2013-07-23 09:34:53 INFO  [http-8080-2] CompanyDaoImpl.java:157 - Entering insertCompanyData
2013-07-23 09:34:53 ERROR [http-8080-2] ErrorCounter.java:56 - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
2013-07-23 09:34:53 ERROR [http-8080-2] ErrorCounter.java:56 - <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: {vector}
2013-07-23 09:34:53 INFO  [http-8080-2] CompanyMasterServiceImpl.java:121 - Entering buildCompanyMasterDropdowns .. 
2013-07-23 09:34:53 INFO  [http-8080-2] CodesDaoImpl.java:27 - Entering findCodesByType()
Hibernate: select this_.CODE_MASTER_ID as CODE1_8_0_, this_.CR_TS as CR2_8_0_, this_.CR_USR as CR3_8_0_, this_.MD_TS as MD4_8_0_, this_.MD_USR as MD5_8_0_, this_.CODE_ID as CODE6_8_0_, this_.CODE_MASTER_TYPE as CODE7_8_0_, this_.CODE_DESC as CODE8_8_0_, this_.STATUS as STATUS8_0_ from FBMS.MST_CODE this_ where this_.CODE_MASTER_TYPE=? and this_.STATUS=? order by this_.CODE_DESC asc
2013-07-23 09:34:53 INFO  [http-8080-2] CodesDaoImpl.java:33 - Exiting findCodesByType() ..
```

please suggest how to rectify this error...

Answer (score 0):

The select part of your query must be a valid HQL select query, returning columns matching the ones specified in the insert clause.

If you want to insert a new row, from values you have in memory, into your table, just use `persist()`:

```
CompanyMaster c = new CompanyMaster();
c.setName(someName);
...
session.persist(c);
```